# Google cloud compute engine - startup script - How to start java spring application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Compute Engine instance with a java spring application

How can I execute it on my VM Instance startup ?  If i start my VM, it should execute my application automatically.
Looking at the article -[google doc](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-springboot-compute-engine)
(the document does a lot, but I only need to run the existing war artifact)

I added a few lines - editing VM - Automation >> Startup script

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/souin/p****my/build/libs
# Start server
java -jar py*****my-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

[image]

It is not working.

Do I need to create a shell file inside VM and make use of it from startup ?

Please advice how to run my application?

Comment: Can you share if there is any error message showing when you try to run your application? And have you tried running it through SSH?

Comment: @DionV I am expecting an answer from you google guys. when I ran with above, it just started VM. and the app did not start.  I think I remember seeing error related to spring - logback-test etc ( normal SSH and issuing java command works). But I would say do not read all this, instead get a sample on how to issue a java command from startup script

Comment: @Ashish no answer yet. google issue tracker accepted as a feature with No ETA.

Comment: Thanks for responding @KrisSwat , please update if you find any other solutions